# Save in a list of tuples the values of dates and times of all the OUTGOING events

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

outgoing event means where the value of 'from' = 4
can someone help with the code. I'm stuck.

```
eg:
({'date': '20090328',
  'time': '061546',
  'from': '4',
  'to': '12',
  'cell_tower': '220',
  'event_type': 'MOC'},
 {'date': '20090328',
  'time': '053359',
  'from': '4',
  'to': '2',
  'cell_tower': '221',
  'event_type': 'SOM'},
)
```

json file :

```
{'user': '4', 'data': [{'date': '20090328', 'time': '061546', 'from': '4', 'to': '12', 'cell_tower': '220', 'event_type': 'MOC'}, {'date': '20090328', 'time': '053359', 'from': '4', 'to': '2', 'cell_tower': '221', 'event_type': 'SOM'}, {'date': '20090328', 'time': '012339', 'from': '6', 'to': '4', 'cell_tower': '14054', 'event_type': 'MOC'}
```

Comment: what is the input data (a list)? also, please show your code and the issue you are facing with it.

Comment: What you have shared is not a valid python data structure. Please share a valid data structure, what would you like to do with the data and the code you currently have.

Comment: i had a json file. i loaded it in python.

Comment: add some part of the json file and the code that you have.

Comment: @Ozil I also recommend using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ to format your json outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using this json file named `filename.json`:

```
{
  "user": "4",
  "data": [
    {
      "date": "20090328",
      "time": "061546",
      "from": "4",
      "to": "12",
      "cell_tower": "220",
      "event_type": "MOC"
    },
    {
      "date": "20090328",
      "time": "053359",
      "from": "4",
      "to": "2",
      "cell_tower": "221",
      "event_type": "SOM"
    },
    {
      "date": "20090328",
      "time": "012339",
      "from": "6",
      "to": "4",
      "cell_tower": "14054",
      "event_type": "MOC"
    }
  ]
}
```

The python code would look like this:

```
import json

outgoing = '4'
tuples = []

file = open('filename.json')

events = json.load(file)['data']
for event in events:
    if event['from'] == outgoing:
        tuples.append((event['date'], event['time']))

file.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but im getting an error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Ozil Had to change `'` to `"` in the `filename.json` file and convert the string `'filename.json'` to a file pointer

Comment: @Ozil As well as add a missing end bracket`]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your input data is not in a valid `json` format as `json` requires double quotes around its values.

You need to first read the data and replace all `'` with `"` and then use json to format as a `json` object and then use list comprehension to get the result.

```
import json

with open('inp.json', 'r') as f:
    inp = f.read()                             # load data from file
    inp = inp.replace("'", "\"")               # replace ' with "
    inp = json.loads(inp)                      # create a json object
    output = [(data['date'], data['time']) for data in inp['data'] if data['from'] == '4']
    for out in output:
        print(out)
```

Output:

```
('20090328', '061546')
('20090328', '053359')
```

Answer (score 0):

see below (one liner )

```
data = {
    'user': '4',
    'data': [
        {
            'date': '20090328',
            'time': '061546',
            'from': '4',
            'to': '12',
            'cell_tower': '220',
            'event_type': 'MOC'
        },
        {
            'date': '20090328',
            'time': '053359',
            'from': '4',
            'to': '2',
            'cell_tower': '221',
            'event_type': 'SOM'
        },
        {
            'date': '20090328',
            'time': '012339',
            'from': '6',
            'to': '4',
            'cell_tower': '14054',
            'event_type': 'MOC'
        }
    ]
}

tuples = [(e['date'], e['time']) for e in data['data'] if e['from'] == '4']
print(tuples)
```

output

```
[('20090328', '061546'), ('20090328', '053359')]
```

Comment: im getting an error TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: @Ozil - do you take my code and run it as is? If you do, I dont think you get an error. Please explain what do you do.

Comment: works perfectly fine thanks a lot. how can I get the output in new lines, rather than in the same line to make it presentable?

Comment: @Ozil - run a for loop over the `tuples` and print them one by one